# Pyspark: AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();

Tags: pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I have multiple functions that I want to run but I get an error that says I need to use `.start()`. Can someone show me how to proceed?
Here is a part of my code:

```
def parse_data(df):
    cachedDf = df.cache()
    # Do some more logics 
    return df.collect()

def convert_to_local_time(df):
    # Logic for converting to localtime
    return df
    

raw_stream_df = spark.readStream.format("delta").load(raw_table_path)

df = parse_data(raw_stream_df)
df = convert_to_local_time(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an working example of how to do structured streaming properly.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SQLContext, SparkContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *


sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

data1 = [

[1, 35,"Male","2023-10-01",200],
[1, 35,"Male","2023-10-02",210],
[2, 28,"Female","2023-10-01",150],
[2, 28,"Female","2023-10-02",160],

]

columns =["member_id", "age", "gender", "date", "cost"]

df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema=columns)

df1.show(n=10, truncate=False)



tempdir = "../data/structstream/"
df1.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").save(tempdir)

dataframeSchema = StructType([
                StructField("member_id",IntegerType(),False),
                StructField("age",IntegerType(),False),
                StructField("gender",StringType(),False),
                StructField("date",StringType(),False),
                StructField("cost",IntegerType(),False),

            ])

streaming_df = sqlContext.readStream \
    .schema(dataframeSchema) \
    .csv(tempdir)

transformed_stream = streaming_df.withColumn("date_casted", F.to_date(F.col("date"))) \
                            .withColumn("something_here", F.lit("hello_world"))

query = transformed_stream.writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("console") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

Output :

```
+---------+---+------+----------+----+
|member_id|age|gender|date      |cost|
+---------+---+------+----------+----+
|1        |35 |Male  |2023-10-01|200 |
|1        |35 |Male  |2023-10-02|210 |
|2        |28 |Female|2023-10-01|150 |
|2        |28 |Female|2023-10-02|160 |
+---------+---+------+----------+----+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+---------+---+------+----------+----+-----------+--------------+
|member_id|age|gender|      date|cost|date_casted|something_here|
+---------+---+------+----------+----+-----------+--------------+
|        1| 35|  Male|2023-10-01| 200| 2023-10-01|   hello_world|
|        1| 35|  Male|2023-10-02| 210| 2023-10-02|   hello_world|
|        2| 28|Female|2023-10-01| 150| 2023-10-01|   hello_world|
|        2| 28|Female|2023-10-02| 160| 2023-10-02|   hello_world|
+---------+---+------+----------+----+-----------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite the intended way to use streaming DataFrames. You're creating the streaming DataFrame correctly with `.format("delta").load(...)`, but at this point, you really want to do SQL operations like filtering, projecting, aggregating, etc. You can find some examples [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#basic-operations---selection-projection-aggregation).

Concretely, instead of passing `raw_stream_df` to different functions one-by-one, you could do something like:

```
# Transform your raw DataFrame to get another DataFrame
df = raw_stream_df.filter("foo > 5").groupBy("bar").count()

# Create a DataStreamWriter by specifying the sink format
data_stream_writer = df.writeStream.format("delta")

# Start your query
data_stream_writer.start()
```

In total, the basic steps for writing a query should be:

1. Use a source to create a DataFrame (you got this far)
2. Transform your DataFrame using the Structured Streaming APIs
3. Use `.writeStream` to tell Structured Streaming about your sink
4. Start your query with `.start()`

Note that `.start()` will start the query in the background, so the method will return even as the stream runs.

Comment: I think need to mention that I will use mico-batch to process my data. With that said, I should be able to follow your bullet 2 and then 3 and 4, like this?`read_stream_df.writeStream.option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_path).foreachBatch(save_to_raw_layer).queryName(topic_name).trigger(once=True).start()`